# Why is my GCD program in C not running?

Tags: c, algorithm, function, recursion, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to find the GCD of two numbers using Euclid's algorithm in C (recursively) and I do know that mathematically it's not completely perfect yet as it neglects negative number conditions, but I just want this one to work for positive numbers for now.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gcd(int m, int n);

int main() {
    return gcd(60, 24);
}

int gcd(int m, int n) {
    if (m < n) {
        //swapping both a and b
        m = m + n;
        n = m - n;
        m = m - n;
    }
    if (m == n) {
        return m;
    } else {
        return gcd(n, m % n);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Your termination condition is not broad enough; not always does eventually m==n hold at the end of the (actual) algorithm. Examples help (e.g. gcd(4, 2) -> gcd(2, 0)...)

Comment: Yeah that's true, but afaik for all positive numbers, it eventually comes down to zero, besides the main point that I want to know is why does this program not run for gcd(60,24) which I am pretty sure that will come to zero if we follow Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: Well, (60, 24) -> (24, 12) -> (12, 0). Your algorithm continues. And this is bad...

Comment: Most cases will eventually reach `(m, 0)` as the final iteration.  At that point, it needs to return `m`.  Instead, it will try to evaluate `m % 0` which of course will cause an error.  Change the `m == n` condition to `n == 0` to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Pachelbel and @Tom Karzes Thanks a lot. Although I kept that m==n condition to stop from getting the program to enter calculation because it's quite evident that gcd would be m if m==n. So I will just add another check for if(n==0) instead of just replacing m==n if statement. Thanks. :D

Comment: The swapping method you have chosen is sensible to overflow. Use a temporary variable or avoid swapping completely.

Comment: Look at the solution posted by user3386109.  It avoids the swapping completely, and is simpler and more efficient than the other solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gcd(60, 24)` -> `gcd(24, 12)` -> `gcd(12, 0)`.

That means you need to add a check.

```
if ( n == 0 )
{
   return m;
}
```

or

```
if ( m%n == 0 )
{
   return n;
}
```

You can also remove the variable swapping code with another call to the function with the values swapped in the call.

```
int gcd(int m, int n) {

   if (m < n) {
      return gcd(n, m);
   }

   if (m%n == 0) {
      return n;
   } else {
      return gcd(n, m % n);   
   }
}
```

Comment: This should replace the `m == n` check.  I.e., it isn't an added check, it's a corrected check.

Comment: This solution performs two `%` operations per iteration, when only one is needed (unless the compiler common subs the operation).  A much better solution is to simply check for a zero operand.  Not to mention the fact that this solution fails if an operand is zero (which no good gcd algorithm will do).

Comment: @TomKarzes, I toyed with the idea of using the first condition - `if ( n == 0 ) return m;`. I hesitated because I wasn't sure what the mathematical definition of gcd between a non-zero number and zero is. What happens when the call from `main` is `gcd(20, 0)`. I realize that call will crash the program. The question remains in mind nonetheless.

Comment: Take a look at the solution posted by user3386109.  It's much simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @TomKarzes, it's cleaner for sure. I can't tell for sure that it is more efficient.

Comment: Of course it's more efficient.  Look at the work done per iteration in the non-terminal case:  This one does two interger `%` operations, two comparisons, two conditional branches.  The other solution does one comparison, one conditional branch, and one integer `%` operation.  Depending on call overhead, it could potentially be as much as twice as fast.

Comment: @TomKarzes, what you say makes sense.

Comment: `if ( m%n == 0 )
{
   return n;
}` leads to UB when `n == 0`.

Answer (score 7):

The code for a recursive GCD looks like this

```
int gcd(int m, int n)
{
    if (n==0)
        return m;

    return gcd(n, m % n);
}
```

There is no need to swap arguments, since that will be taken care of by the recursion. For example, consider `gcd(24, 60)`. In this case `n=60` and `m % n = 24%60 = 24`. So the recursive call is `gcd(60,24)`, swapping the arguments automatically.

Comment: Yes, this is much cleaner and more efficient than the solution that was accepted.

Comment: Only cases with UB found are `gcd(INT_MIN,-1)`, `gcd(-1, INT_MIN)`.  `gcd()` is really meant for unsigned arguments.