# Given thr GCD(=1) and one number, find the second number

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out a way to solve this problem. The user has to input a number N, and the program has to print the numbers that have GCD= 1  between them and N.
If the input is 5, then the program should print "1 2 3 4".
For input 6, then print should be "1 5".
Yet my code doesn't print anything. Could anyone help me out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (a==b)
        return a;
    else
        if(a<b)
        return gcd(a, b-a);
    else
        return gcd(a-b, b);

}


int main()
{
        int i=0;
        long int n;
        scanf("%ld", &n);

        if (n<1 || n>999999999)
         printf("Wrong Input");

        else
        {
              for(i=0; i<=n ; i++)
              {
                  gcd(n, i);
                  if (gcd(n,i)==1)
                      printf("%d ", i);
              }

        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's a nitpicky thing, but when you are asking others to read your code the least you could do is try to make it as readable as possible. Fix the formatting.

Comment: `for(i=0;` should be `for(i=1;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int _gcd(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a % b;
    if (c == 0)
        return b;
    return _gcd(b, c);
}

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b ? _gcd(a, b) : _gcd(b, a);
}
```

In addition to that, you obviously need to change this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

To this:

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
```

Comment: [You don't need the extra layer in the `gcd` code to swap arguments.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35096165/3386109)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the loop

for (int i=0;i<=n;i++)  to   (int i=1;i<=n;i++) because zero has infinity of divisors

```
int main()
{
    int found=0;
    long n;
    scanf("%ld", &n);
    if (n<1 || n>999999999)
            printf("Wrong Input");
    else
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=n ; i++)
        {
            gcd(i, n);
            if (gcd(n,i)==1)
                printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
 }
 int gcd(int a, int b)
 {
      if (a==b)
      {
           return a;
      }
      else if(a<b)
      {
          return gcd(a, b-a);
      }
      else
      {
           return gcd(a-b, b);
      }
   }
```

Comment: This code may be correct, but explain what you changed and why.

Comment: @RetiredNinja ,I changed the loop
for (int i=0;i<=n;i++) to (int i=1;i<=n;i++) because zero has infinity of divisors